# Illegal Invocation jQuery HTML5 Audio Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

## Background

Basically, this code takes all of the audio tags on the page, and when one finishes it starts the next one in the DOM.

## The Issue

When `fnPlay` is called I receive an `Illegal Invocation` error.

```
//THIS CODE FAILS
var lastAudio = null;
$('audio').each(function(index) {
    var fnPlay = $(this)[0].play;
    if (lastAudio != null) {
        lastAudio.bind("ended", function() {
            fnPlay(); 
        });
    }
    lastAudio = $(this);
});
```

Now I am **sure** that the rest of the code is fine, because the following worked.

```
//WORKS GREAT!
var lastAudio = null;
$('audio').each(function(index) {
    var lastAudioObj = $(this)[0];
    if (lastAudio != null) {
        lastAudio.bind("ended", function() {
            lastAudioObj.play(); 
        });
    }
    lastAudio = $(this);
});
```

## Question

Can anybody explain why I couldn't store the `play()` function inside my variable `fnPlay` and call `fnPlay()`, but I could store the object and call the `play()` function on the object?

Comment: the basic of this is the `this` reference .... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the context of JavaScript functions work.  The context (or `this`) inside a function is set when it's *ran*, not when it's set.

When you call `lastAudioObj.play();`, the `play()` function is called in the context of `lastAudioObj`.  Inside `play()`, `this` is `lastAudioObj`, so everything works.

When you do `fnPlay()` however, it has no context.  `this` inside the function will be `null` (or `window`).  `play()` doesn't like that, so it throws an exception.

There are a few ways to fix this.

One is to call the function with `.call()` to manually set the context.

Set the variables like:

```
var lastAudioObj = $(this)[0];
var fnPlay = lastAudioObj.play;
```

Then call:

```
fnPlay.call(lastAudioObj);
```

You can also use `.bind()` to set the context when setting the variable.

```
var lastAudioObj = $(this)[0];
var fnPlay = lastAudioObj.play.bind(lastAudioObj);
```

Then you can just call it like:

```
fnPlay();
```